# Mustache JS templating and unknown properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, javascript-objects, mustache

I'm trying to use mustache JS templates dynamically. I'll have an array of templates like so:

```
var tmpls = [
   '<p>{{name}}</p>',
   '<p><b>{{car}}</b></p>'
];
```

and then I want to pick the correct template based on the index of something... which I can do like:

```
var stuff = {
      name: 'bob'
}

$.mustache(tmpls[index], stuff);
```

but I'm not quite sure how to fill the values based on something else such as input IDs and their values:

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="Bob" />
<input type="text" id="car" value="Corsa" />

$.mustache(tmpls[index], {
    $('input').eq(0).attr('id') : $('input').eq(0).val()
});
```

I guess I'm trying to create an object to pass mustache dynamically. The property names are the IDs of the input fields and the values are from the input field.

Is this possible?

Thanks, Dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to build your stuff object is by iterating through the elements using `.each()`:

```
var stuff = {};

$('input').each(function() {
    stuff[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
});

$.mustache(tmpls[index], stuff);
```

Comment: Ah yeah of course... In the end I tried creating a string and then I used $.parseJSON on the string I created and passed that. I never thought of doing it like an associative array to create the parameter names... thanks :D